# Как сделать парсинг страницы?

Tags: c#, синтаксический-анализ

Имеется код C#:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string urik = "http://www.cy-pr.com/analysis/";

    foreach(string s in richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n'))
    {
        string retVal = new WebClient().DownloadString(urik + s);
        richTextBox2.Text = "Подставляем сайты... ";
    }
}
```

В `richTextBox1` имеется список сайтов, которые нужно по очереди подставлять, и после каждого "поставления" загружается web-страница, например, подставили "vk.com": `http://www.cy-pr.com/analysis/ya.ru/` и нужно с этой страницы скопировать Яндекс тИЦ (CY) и Google PageRank (PR). У сайта [ya.ru](http://ya.ru) показатель ТиЦ будет равен "12000", он в html вроде находится между символами: `"inline;"> 12000 </span>`, а PR google будет равен 6, в html выглядит так: `id="pr">6</span>`.

Как скопировать ТиЦ и PR с каждого сайта и сложить результат Тиц отдельно (тиц всех сайтов сложить), а PR отдельно высчитать со всех сайтов и вывести?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Могу подсказать регулярные выражения, а как из использовать в си# читайте в интернете.  
ТиЦ:  

    \"inline;\"> (\d+) <\/span>
PR:  

    id=\"pr\">(\d+)<\/span>
В обоих выражениях результат возвращается в первой группе.

Answer (score 3):

Эту задачу проще решать с помощью [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), поскольку она уже содержит многое для разбора веб-страниц. Например, чтобы получить конкретный span на странице по конкретному id делают так:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();

document.Load("foo.html");

var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='something']");
if (node != null)
{
    var innerText = node.InnerText;
    // Получить текст внутри span
}
```